# Does Django re-run all migrations for it's test db?

Tags: django, database-migration, django-testing, django-tests

I am trying to run `python manage.py test` and it starts off with the usual `Creating test database for alias 'default'...` but then a `pymysql.err.InternalError` occurs with the message `"Invalid default value for 'expiration_time'"`. expiration_time is a timestamp variable with the default value as null. One reason that I can think of why this error is occuring is probably because all migrations are being re-run and that this might not be an acceptable default value but I could not find any information on how the test db is actually created by django.

Comment: And this error didnt occur when you ran `migrate` command for your server database?

Comment: did you tried this package, ? https://pypi.org/project/django-test-without-migrations/

Comment: Can you add the model ?

Comment: @SachinKukreja I'm working on a project started by someone else so unfortunately there are no models. View files access db via custom libs and update the db directly.

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge not yet, thanks for pointing it out will try it

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/08/19/django-tip-12-disabling-migrations-to-speed-up-unit-tests.html